# Is vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the same that $\mathfrak{M}_{n\times 1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Being $\mathfrak{M}_{n\times 1}$ a vector space of matrix of $n$ rows and $1$ columns.

I  can't found a substantial difference between $\mathfrak{M}_{n\times 1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Both have the same properties and I saw in Linear Algebra's books that are used interchangeably.

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "*the same.*"  They are effectively the same for all intents and purposes and are indeed used interchangeably.  As for if they are identically equal, well, that depends on how they are formally defined.  $(A\times B)\times C$ is not necessarily formally identical to $A\times (B\times C)$ though they share many properties.

Answer (score 0):

Yes . The map $$(x_1,x_2,\cdots x_n) \longmapsto \begin{pmatrix}x_1 &x_2& \cdots&x_n  \end{pmatrix}^T \in M_{n \times 1}$$ is an isomorphism. So we can identify $M_{n \times 1}$ by $\Bbb R^n$. Consequently, $M_{n \times n}$ can be identified with $\Bbb R^{n^2}$